# How can I convert from OpenGL GLSL code to OpenGL ES GLSL code

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I am trying to convert glsl for opengl to glsl for opengl es.

Here is glsl code that I'm going to translate.

- For vertex shader

  ```
  varying vec2 texcoord0;
  varying vec2 texcoord1;
  varying vec2 texcoord2;
  varying vec2 texcoord3;
  varying vec2 texcoord4;
  varying vec2 texdim0;

  varying vec2 texcoordLUT;

  uniform float sharpness;

  void main()
  {
      gl_Position = ftransform();

      texcoord0 = vec2(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0);
      texcoordLUT = vec2(gl_TextureMatrix[1] * gl_MultiTexCoord1);
      texdim0 = vec2 (abs(gl_TextureMatrix[0][0][0]),abs(gl_TextureMatrix[0][1][1]));

      texcoord1 = texcoord0 + vec2(-sharpness, -sharpness);
      texcoord2 = texcoord0 + vec2(+sharpness, -sharpness);
      texcoord3 = texcoord0 + vec2(+sharpness, +sharpness);
      texcoord4 = texcoord0 + vec2(-sharpness, +sharpness);

  }
  ```
- For fragment shader

  ```
  uniform float amount;
  uniform float vignette;

  uniform sampler4DRect tex0;
  uniform sampler1D tex1;

  varying vec2 texcoord0;
  varying vec2 texcoord1;
  varying vec2 texcoord2;
  varying vec2 texcoord3;
  varying vec2 texcoord4;

  varying vec2 texdim0;

  varying vec2 texcoordLUT;

  const vec4 one = vec4(1.0); 
  const vec4 two = vec4(2.0);
  const vec4 lumcoeff = vec4(0.299,0.587,0.114, 0.);

  vec4 vignetteFucntion(vec2 normalizedTexcoord)
  {
      normalizedTexcoord = 2.0 * normalizedTexcoord - 1.0;
      float r = length(normalizedTexcoord);
      return 1.0 - vec4(smoothstep(0.5,1.0,r)) + 0.5;
  }

  vec4 hardlight(vec4 a, vec4 b, float amount)
  {
      vec4 result;
      vec4 branch1;
      vec4 branch2;
      float luminance = dot(b,lumcoeff);
      float mixamount;

      mixamount = clamp((luminance - 0.45) * 10., 0., 1.);
      branch1 = two * a * b;
      branch2 = one - (two * (one - a) * (one - b));

      result =  mix(branch1,branch2, vec4(mixamount));

      return mix(a,result, amount);
  }

  void main (void) 
  {       
      vec2 normcoord = texcoord0/texdim0;

      vec4 vignetteResult = vignetteFucntion(normcoord);

      vec4 input0 = texture2DRect(tex0, texcoord0);
      vec4 input1 = texture2DRect(tex0, texcoord1);
      vec4 input2 = texture2DRect(tex0, texcoord2);
      vec4 input3 = texture2DRect(tex0, texcoord3);
      vec4 input4 = texture2DRect(tex0, texcoord4);

      vec4 sharpened = 5.0 * input0 - (input1 + input2 + input3 + input4);

      vec4 hardlighted = hardlight(sharpened,input0, .5);

      vec4 saturated = mix(vec4(dot(hardlighted,lumcoeff)), hardlighted, 0.75);

      vec4 result;

      result.r = texture1D(tex1, saturated.r).r;
      result.g = texture1D(tex1, saturated.g).g;
      result.b = texture1D(tex1, saturated.b).b;
      result.a = saturated.a;

      gl_FragColor = mix(input0, result *  (mix(vec4(1.0),vignetteResult, vignette)),amount);
  }
  ```

I want to know how I can translate gl_TextureMatrix[0], gl_TextureMatrix[1], and gl_TextureMatrix[0][0][0].
What do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gl_TextureMatrix is a transform matrix that transforms the texture coordinates (for example if you wanted to rotate or scale the texture on a static shape.

It is a deprecated built-in variable in standard OpenGL. The proper way to handle this in modern OpenGL/OpenGLES would be to declare your own uniform matrices instead of using the built-in `gl_TextureMatrix`, and update these uniform matrices instead of performing rotations/translations to OpenGL's `GL_TEXTURE_MATRIX`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  texcoord0 = vec2(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0);
    texcoordLUT = vec2(gl_TextureMatrix[1] * gl_MultiTexCoord1);  Would you please kindly explain these lines?  I can't understand.

Comment: I can't explain it without some kind of idea of what you already know. What **specifically** about it do you not understand? I can try to help you if there's some specific aspect of OpenGLES that confuses you, but I'm not going to explain the entirety of OpenGL if you're just trying to duplicate someone's shader without having any understanding of how it works or why.

Comment: this is the shader that applies Lomo effect to video frame.  I'm using it with GPUImage.  I copied other's code and trying to understand.  I am googling but can't find any description of gl_TextureMatrix.  As I know, it's 4x4 float 2 dimensional array.  I understood it like as e.g. float gl_TextureMatrix[4][4];  But in this code, used gl_TextureMatrix[0][0][0], what does this mean?  Plz help me.

Comment: I believe that gl_TextureMatrix is actually an **array** of 4x4 float arrays, so that you can have multiple matrices (this is so you can have different transformations for different layers in multitexturing). So [0][0][0] just means first row, first column of the texture matrix at index 0. You have to understand transformations in general if you want to understand gl_TextureMatrix. It's just a typical 4x4 transformation matrix that changes coordinates from one space into another.

Comment: @Piao - Also, I should add that vignetting, sharpening, hard light blends, etc. are all built into GPUImage as filters anyway, so you don't need to implement your own version of that. Others have created a Lomo effect by chaining them appropriately. You should be able to assemble this all without having to write your own shader.